# Dynamically displaying text in Gridview when link is clicked

Tags: .net, gridview

I have a gridview set up and I'd like to have it so that when an item (link) is clicked, hidden fields that correspond to the item's record will be shown.  This seems like something JQuery could handle but I have no idea how to implement it.

I'm looking for something along the lines of: a list of homeowners is pulled from a SQL database into the Gridview.  If you click on a specific name, the homeowner's address will be displayed.

I'm doing this all in .NET.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might be looking for this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailstemplate(v=vs.110).aspx  And just bing the data down up front rather than making multiple trips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention `.Net` and `GridView` so I'm going to assume you mean a Web Application.

GridView's allow you to get creative.  If you're familiar with Template Fields then imagine and address "card" associated with name, or in this case, and icon.

In my world the classes `rs-icon` and `rs-icon-vcard` display an rolodex style icon image that is associated with a a hidden div: `<div id="ContactInfo" class="Hide">`

The class `tooltip-marker` is an anonymous CSS class that is only used to identify the parent of the hidden `ContactInfo` div via jquery

After the page is rendered and in the jquery ready() function I make a jquery call to jqueryui's tooltip().  Mousing over the icon will trigger a popup tooltip that displays the hidden, formatted "vcard" :

```
$( function() {
  $( document ).tooltip( {
    items: ".tooltip-marker",
    content: function() {
        return $( this ).children( "div" ).html()
    },
    position: {
        my: "left top",
        at: "right+5 top-5"
    }
  } );
} );
```

This is a snippet of the GridView.  I only used a single datasource which, among many other fields, supplies the contact information that you see laid out here.  The drawback is that all the information is supplied and made available (though hidden) regardless of the users needs.  For my needs since I'm only display 10 rows at a time the overhead is acceptable.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Info">
  <HeaderStyle Width="32px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="50px" />
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="rs-icon rs-icon-vcard tooltip-marker">
      <div id="ContactInfo" class="Hide">
        <table id="tblContactDetail" class="ContactDetail">
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 80px">Name</td>
            <td style="width: 100%">
              <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("expert_name") %>' />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>
              <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address_1") %>'></asp:Literal>
              <asp:Literal ID="Literal3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address_2") %>'></asp:Literal>
              <asp:Literal ID="Literal4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address_3") %>'></asp:Literal>
              <asp:Literal ID="Literal5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("csz") %>'></asp:Literal>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td><asp:Literal ID="Literal6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Phone_Number") %>'></asp:Literal></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>
              <asp:Literal ID="Literal7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email_Address") %>'></asp:Literal>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```